# Arcpy: Exporting PNGs with high quality using data driven pages

Tags: arcpy, data-driven-pages

I am using data driven pages and want to automatically export my layouts/extents to PNG. Since you have to use arcpy to export to PNG with data driven pages, I used following code, as explained here: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00sm00000008000000

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
for pageNum in range(1, mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageCount + 1):
    mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID = pageNum
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToPNG(mxd, r"C:\Temp\ParcelAtlas_Page" +str(pageNum) + ".png")
del mxd
```

The problem is that the quality is very bad when I export like this. If I export to PNG manually, and set for example 300 dpi, it is way better than exporting automatically.

Would you know a solution to export in better quality using arcpy and data driven pages in ArcMap?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The output resolution of the ExportToPNG tool is 96 dpi by default, but you can modify it, see the [help page](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s30000002s000000) of the tool.

```
arcpy.mapping.ExportToPNG(mxd, r"C:\Temp\ParcelAtlas_Page" +str(pageNum) + ".png", resolution=300)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the [documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/exporttopng.htm#) it states you can specify the resolution in the method call (which defaults to 96), or there is the export width and height as follows:

```
arcpy.mapping.ExportToPNG(mxd, r"C:\Project\Output\ProjectDataFrame.png", df,
                          df_export_width=1600,
                          df_export_height=1200)
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the python syntax for adding transparent background in PNG export?

I used `transparent_color ='True'` and I get an error as below:

```py
TypeError: exportToPNG() got an unexpected keyword argument 'transparent_color'
```

Here the full code:

```py
import arcpy, os, sys
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(r"D:\Working folder\ArcGIS Pro\THUMBNAILS\THUMBNAIL 800X800.aprx")
l = aprx.listLayouts("global map")[0]
ms = l.mapSeries
print (ms)
for pageNum in range(1, ms.pageCount + 1, 1):
        ms.currentPageNumber = pageNum
        region_name = str(ms.pageRow.WHO_REGION)
        country_name = str(ms.pageRow.ADM0_NAME)
        output_name = '{}_{}'.format(country_name,region_name)
        print('Exporting {}'.format(output_name))   
        l.exportToPNG((r"D:\Working folder\ArcGIS Pro\THUMBNAILS\OUTPUTS\thumbnails\{0}".format(output_name)+ ".png"),transparent_color= 'True',resolution=72)
```